# Converter HTML em PDF e inserir Image com Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

A imagem não aparece no PDF, eu uso o xhtml2pdf.

**relatorios/sol_acesso.html**

```
<img src="{% static 'img/small_logo.png' %}" alt="Blue Tech" style="max-width:200px; margin-top:10px">
```

**view.py**
`

```
def get(self, request, pk, model):
    projeto = Projeto.objects.select_related('cliente').get(cliente_id=pk)
    try:
        uc = Uc_principal.objects.select_related('cliente').get(cliente_id=pk)
    except Uc_principal.DoesNotExist:
        uc = ''

    context = {
        'projeto': projeto,
        'uc': uc,
    }

    if model == '0':
        pdf = render(request, 'relatorios/sol_acesso.html', context)
        return pdf

    elif model == '1':
        pdf = render_to_pdf('relatorios/sol_acesso.html', context)

    else:
        pdf = render_to_pdf('relatorios/ver_cliente.html', context)

    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Invoice{}.pdf".format("12341231")
        content = "inline; filename=01_{}".format('Nome')
        download = request.GET.get("download")
        if download:
            content = "attachment; filename=01_{}".format('Nome')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

**util.py**

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

**Detalhe:** Se eu não converter em PDF a imagem aparece.

Comment: Jovem aqui no PT.StackOverflow vc pode escrever em português, considere traduzir sua pergunta.

Comment: Verdade, eu esqueci e que tava publicando no pt. kkkkkk

Comment: Voce verificou se é pelo endereço da imagem estar relativo? Talvez tenha que colocar o endereço completo para ele não se perder.

Comment: @KarlZillner Verdade. Colocando o endereço completo ela aparece. Vllw. Vou ver oq posso fazer agora.